# cv::goodFeaturesToTrack doesn't return any features

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow

I'm trying to use [`cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-pointpolygontest) but sometimes an internal assertion in that function fails. The assertion is `npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0`. I'm using OpenCV 2.3.1. The source code for this function is available [here](http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/branches/2.3/opencv/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp).

It's hard to wrap my head around their code, especially because of my limited experience with computer graphics and their lack of comments. Why is this assertion being triggered and what does it say about my problem?

**Edit**: I call the function as follows:

```
cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(curBwFrame, prvFrame, features, newFeatures, trackingStatus, errors);
```

I found out that the `features` vector, which was obtained by calling `cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(curBwFrame, features, 5, 0.2, 0.5, skinMask);` with a non-empty mask that appears to be sufficiently big and a valid image, doesn't contain any features. How can this happen?

**curBwFrame**

[image: curBwFrame]

**skinMask**

[image: skinMask]

I'm able to reproduce the problem using the following code snippet:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using std::vector;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    vector<Point2f> features;
    cv::Mat curBwFrame = imread("curBwFrame.png");
    cv::cvtColor(curBwFrame, curBwFrame, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    imwrite("test.png", curBwFrame);

    cv::Mat skinMask = imread("skinMask.png");
    cv::cvtColor(skinMask, skinMask, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    imwrite("test.png", skinMask);

    cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(curBwFrame, features, 5, 0.2, 0.5, skinMask);
    assert(features.size() > 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The assertions checks that input argument is a vector of points. And it's hard to answer your question without your code.

Comment: I've added more information above, but I'm not sure what other information might be relevant. I could dump some big code snippets here but they would likely contains lots of irrelevant information.

Comment: Sorry about my mixing up some function calls earlier. I added the correct snippet above! I can post the mask and the source image for `goodFeaturesToTrack` too if it's necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem are your parameters.In the [OpenCV 2.3.2 documentation](http://www.opencv.org.cn/opencvdoc/2.3.2/html/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html) (no compatibility change between 2.3.1) this is the description of the method parameters:

```
void goodFeaturesToTrack(InputArray image, OutputArray corners, int maxCorners, double qualityLevel, double minDistance, InputArray mask=noArray(), int blockSize=3, bool useHarrisDetector=false, double k=0.04 )
```

Parameters:

- image – Input 8-bit or floating-point 32-bit, single-channel image.
- corners – Output vector of detected corners.
- maxCorners – Maximum number of corners to return. If there are more
  corners than are found, the strongest of them is returned.
- **qualityLevel** – Parameter characterizing the minimal accepted quality
  of image corners. The parameter value is multiplied by the best
  corner quality measure, which is the minimal eigenvalue (see
  cornerMinEigenVal() ) or the Harris function response (see
  cornerHarris() ). The corners with the quality measure less than the
  product are rejected. For example, if the best corner has the quality
  measure = 1500, and the qualityLevel=0.01 , then all the corners with
  the quality measure less than 15 are rejected.
- **minDistance** – Minimum possible Euclidean distance between the
  returned corners.
- mask – Optional region of interest. If the image is    not empty (it
  needs to have the type CV_8UC1 and the same size as    image ), it
  specifies the region in which the corners are detected.
- blockSize – Size of an average block for computing a derivative
  covariation matrix over each pixel neighborhood. See
  cornerEigenValsAndVecs() .
- useHarrisDetector – Parameter indicating whether to use a Harris
  detector (see cornerHarris()) or cornerMinEigenVal().
- k – Free parameter of the Harris detector.

**I recommend you to play a little with qualityLevel and minDistance to suffice your needs.**

Comment: With qualityLevel = 0.1 I was already able to detect 5 features.

Comment: How will a 0.1 value affect the error margin? I know that it will increase, but is this a commonly used quality value or is it considered unreliable?

Comment: What you mean by error margin? goodFeaturesToTrack works on a "grade" classification of each pixel on a window with size blockSize. The biggest this "grade" is, more likely this pixel is a rightly differentiable feature, wich means that if that feature is seen in another conditions, like different ambient lighting or camera pose, it will still be classified as the same feature. If a pixel don't have a big enough grade, it's not classified as a feature. The smaller the qualityLevel, smaller the "grade" necessary to classify a pixel as a feature, making the extracted features less diferentiable.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. That +50 is coming your way!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried goodFeaturesToTrack **without a mask** to see if it detects features inside the masked region? It is possible that, because the image is dark, and the region is a bit textureless, that goodFeaturesToTrack fails to find features there.

You might also try [ORB or FAST](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html) instead of goodFeaturesToTrack. I have successfully used ORB with calcOpticalFlowPyrLK (but didn't try to use a mask).

Or you could try to brighten up the image or even enhance the contrast. Not really sure if this brings improvements because I think the biggest problem of your scenario is that objects in the scene do not have enough texture or corners, which are the more suitable features for these detectors. 
I recommend that you try ORB and see if you get more points.

Comment: When the mask region is omitted, it selects the following pixels: (864, 1170) and (859, 1149). Neither of these points falls inside the mask region. I'm not familiar with ORB and FAST. Where can I find more information about these techniques? I didn't [find](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Aopencv.willowgarage.com%20orb%20fast%20goodfeaturestotrack) the info in their docs.

Comment: If it only detects those points without a mask it most likely confirms what I explained in the answer. I will update it with further information.

Answer (score 0):

Does the image start out in color? Use cv::transform to enhance the color contrast before converting to grey. Shoot for a full range of grey, from 0 to 255. Don't worry about saturating the image outside the mask.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is similar to that:

```
 Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(mCurrentFrame, initial, NUMBER_OF_FEATURES, 0.1, 10); 
 //The OpenCV opticalFlow will crash if the feature vector does not include any elements
 if (initial.elemSize() == 0) {
     return;
 }
 initial.convertTo(mPrevPts, CvType.CV_32FC2);

 Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(mPreviousFrame, mCurrentFrame, mPrevPts, mNextPts, status,err);
```

Make sure you do not forget the statement checking the size of the feature vector (initial.elemSize() == 0).

If this vector is empty, the conversion from a Matrix of point to floating points done by the initial.convertTo() line will not happen and the assertion will show up when calling calOpticalFlowPyrLK